# why it is not posssible to create object for interface and abstract class in java

Tags: java

I know that we can't create object for interface and abstract class. my doubt is why? why can't we create an object for interface and abstract class?
for example

```
class Demo{

 }
Demo demo = new Demo();//it is possible
```

but

```
interface Demo{

}

Demo demo = new Demo();// it is not possible why?
```

Comment: I think interface defines the structure of a class, so it is not a class by itself.

Comment: I heard that interface internally acts as super class. and in according to my knowledge in interface we can declare a method, but we can't define it. @Salivan

Answer (score 1):

An `object` in java contains data (class members) and set of operations (methods). These operations are performed on the data stored by the object.

Now both `interface` and `abstract class` don't provide concrete implementation of operations, which could be performed on the object data. Basically `interface` and `abstract classes` in the java are used to define/declare the contract for an object. This contract of operations is later fulfilled by the concrete/complete classes.

So these incomplete objects will be of no use in the application. So java does not allow creating instance of `interface` or `abstract classes`.

Answer (score 0):

Because both interface and abstract class could have abstract methods which doesn't have implementation that's why is unclear what `new Demo().myMethod()` would do.